# Indexing in ltxdoc dtx using doc package

Tags: dtx

I've combed the documentation for a solution to this, and Googled like crazy, but haven't been able to come up with anything.  I'm working on a fairly complex dtx file and have gotten the index working just fine; however, when I tried to create subentries, I instead get normal entries with an opening interrogatory mark replacing `\levelchar`.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Testing some subentries!
\index{small caps}\index{small caps\levelchar petite small caps}
\index{small caps\levelchar and titling caps, difference between}

\PrintIndex

\end{document}
```

I'm compiling this with what as far I can tell are the correct commands:

```
pdflatex indtest.tex;
makeindex -s gind.ist indtest.idx;
pdflatex indtest.tex;
```

I've also tried replacing `\levelchar` with the `!` that I know and love from `makeindex`, but all this does is remove the opening interrogatory mark.  My first thought was that `gind.ist` doesn't support subentries, but the `doc` documentation discusses them, so it seems that it does.

What glaringly obvious issue am I missing here?

Comment: This is supposed to be typeset with verbatim try `\tt` before PrintIndex

Comment: Doesn't seem to resolve the issue; I'm still not getting a true subentry.

Comment: I've found that explicitly including `subitem`s works, but the subentries aren't joined under a single identical entry, but rather grouped separately.  So still no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy solution.  While I would expect `\levelchar` to work, all I needed to do was replace it with `>` explicitly.  E.g.:

```
\index{gnats>and gnus}
```

This creates the appropriate subentries, which are correctly grouped together in the index.